# ClusteredColumns : Gap between clustered bars

Tags: dojox.charting

I have created a Dojo Clustered Columns chart. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AnandVishnu/feW6x/) example

What I want to achieve is to have gap between the clustered columns. So all coke products are clustered together, but say I want some gap between these columns(There is already gap between coke and meat by applying attribute `gap: 10`. What I want is a small gap between the clustered column itself)

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the trick to do it. After analyzing this [example](http://cjolif.github.io/dojo-samples/charting-combine/combine.html) , it occurred to me, to create a gap between stacked column themselves, I just need to make the boundary of the chart as the same color of the background.

My background was white, so I added the following code in my series

```
addSeries("Upmarket", [3,5,5],{stroke: {color:"white"}, fill: "#A31A7E"})
```

Default width is 1. You can control the width of stroke by adding the width property

```
addSeries("Upmarket", [3,5,5],{stroke: {color:"white", width : "4"}, fill: "#A31A7E"})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AnandVishnu/feW6x/1/) UPDATED EXAMLE